# How to specify version with git smart commits?

Tags: git, jira, bitbucket, smart-commits

I'm using BitBucket and Attlasian Jira. They are linked between each other so i can resolve an issues just with git comment:

```
 git commit -m "BUG-123 #resolve #comment My comment"
```

My question is. Is it possible to specify fix version with smart commit feature?

Comment: How could you know the fix version before the version number is finalized?

Comment: e.g. I'm preventing release build. I decided that the next version will be x23.1. I want to commit my changes with link to this version. Not to choose it manualy. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the [JIRA DVCS plugin API documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/using-smart-commits-298976812.html), there are three commands you can use:

```
#time
#comment
#<transition>
```

There is no direct command to use to select the fix version, but you could likely set up a trigger or a hook in the JIRA system that will select a fix version for you upon transition, but there's no way to do it using the defined smart commit commands.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: @JosephLeedy fixed.