# Is it possible to change the assignee in Jira with a Git commit?

Tags: github, jira, dvcs, smart-commits

I am looking for a way to change the assignee of the ticket when I commit code; we have 2 QAs and currently when I commit I can change the Workflow to, for example, **QA** from **In Progress**, and add a comment, but can't find how to change the assignee.

An example of my current commits:

- ADV-99 #qa #comment Fixed abc

Is it possible to have something like this:

- ADV-99 #qa **#assignee:rob** #comment Fixed abc

I cant seem to find anything about changing assignee in the Jira Smart Commits Documentation:
[Using Smart Commits in Jira](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/using-smart-commits-298976812.html)

Note I used the Jira DVCS Connector to connect GitHub to Jira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar Stackoverflow question [How to specify version with git smart commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056567/how-to-specify-version-with-git-smart-commits)

It seems that there are only really 3 commands supported by Jira at the moment:

```
#time
#comment
#<transition>
```

So it would appear I need to either:

- Trigger a change on Transition of the ticket to the QA lane (Which I don't think is an option as there are 2 QAs to whom it can be assigned)
- [Create my own Smart Commit in Jira](https://developer.atlassian.com/fecrudev/tutorials/fisheye-smart-commit-tutorial)